# El servicio PleskStartup se detiene al iniciarlo

Tags: windows, servidor, iis, windows-server, plesk

Me he encontrado con el problema de que el servicio de PleskStartup no se inicia o al iniciarlo, inmediatamente se detiene y por lo tanto no es posible abrir el panel de administración de Plesk.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El único detalle es que tengo mi certificado SSL Wildcard vencido pero desconozco si puede ser por esa razon.
mi server es Windows Server 2016 y administro mis sitios mediante IIS, a Plesk casi no se usa.
Cuando reviso el visor de eventos se muestra lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando se revisa la AppPool siempre está detenida y al iniciarla se vuelve a detener.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco sus comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Para que levantara la AppPool, lo que se le colocó fueron las credenciales del admin, con eso ya se pudo levantar la AppPool y no se vuelve a caer, por lo que he visto el servicio no se ha levantado pero si permite la ejecución.